# Show robots.txt file at domain.com/robots.txt instead of domain.com/context/robots.txt in Spring Java web app

Tags: java, spring, web, robots.txt

I'm trying to add a robots.txt file to my Spring Java web application, but when I put the file in the web app folder, the text is only visible through `localhost:8000/context/robots.txt` instead of `localhost:8000/robots.txt` (the URL that google crawler would check), where I receive a 404 error. I've tried putting the robots.txt file at src, WEB-INF, the project's root folder, etc. with the same results.

I've also tried changing my application-context.xml redirecting "/robots.txt" to my file with `<mvc:resources mapping="/robots.txt" location="/robots.txt" order="0"/>` for all the previous locations and still doesn't work. The index page of my app would be domain.com/context/firstpage.ac so every page is accessible under that context and as I said also the robots.txt file is showed there when I put it on the web app folder.

Is there any way to separate my robots file from the others and put it at localhost:8000/robots.txt or it isn't possible since my app is deployed under that specific context?

Folder-structure:

[image]

Comment: It depends on your actual web server, but some containers have a special folder "ROOT" that installs the application without a "context" in the path, so their contents appear at the top of the domain without the extra string in the path name.

Comment: (We'd need the actual web container and its version to give you the answer definitively.)

Comment: I'm using WebLogic Server 10.3.6. I don't know if that answers your question, I'm afraid I don't know much about this...

Comment: Ok, I have another web app with tomcat and thanks to your comment I've found the ROOT folder and now I'm able to access the robots.txt file at the top of the domain. Do you know if there is by any chance something equivalent for WebLogic? I can't find anything about it.

Comment: I don't know, sorry.  I'm hoping someone with experience with WebLogic can answer the question.  I think you have enough information posted in the question now, we just have to wait for someone to see the question.  If not, try asking again in a couple of days, with "WebLogic" in the title and as a tag too.

Comment: I did a web search for "weblogic context path" and found that you need to add a flag to your weblogic-web-app configuration.  The explanation is a little broken so I'm not sure what is going on here, but the basic info seems to be present: https://blogs.oracle.com/jiechen/weblogic-url-redirect-to-context-path